# Express Routing Using URL Varaibles

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Is there a good express routing tutorial out there? I'm having a hard time finding anything comprehensive. I'm especially interested in getting variables from routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

express.js's document under [request.params](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params) is a starting point.  Here is an example how to get params and query string out of a request:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/user/:name', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello ' + req.params.name + ', id=' + req.query.id);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

So GET /user/john?id=123  prints "hello john, id=123"